# Variance of Poisson Compound Distribution

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, variance

Let $v$ a finite measure on $\mathcal{R}$ and define the Compound Poisson distribution as

$$\text{CPoi}_v=e^{-v(\mathcal{R})}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{v^{*n}}{n!}$$

Suppose now that $v$ is concentrated on $(-1/k,-1/(k+1)] \cup [1/(k+1),1/k)$ for $k=1,2,\dots$.

I know that

$$E[X_k]=\int_{(-1/k,-1/(k+1)] \cup [1/(k+1),1/k)} x v(dx)$$

I have to **prove** that

$$\text{Var}[X_k]=\int_{(-1/k,-1/(k+1)] \cup [1/(k+1),1/k)} x^2 v(dx)$$

I am stuck since $E[X_k]$ is not zero from what I know. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about $k$. You have $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n,\ldots$ iid with distribution $\nu=v/\lambda$ with $\lambda=v(\mathcal{R})$ and $N$ a Poisson random variable of mean $\lambda$ independent of the $Y_i$. Finally you consider
$X=Y_1+\ldots+Y_N$ (with the convention $X=0$ if $N=0.$) You are asked to find the variance of $X$ in terms of $\nu$ or $v.$ Use the two formulas
$$E(N)=\lambda, \ E(N(N-1))=\lambda^2$$ that you can prove by derivating twice
$$z\mapsto E(z^N)=e^{\lambda(z-1)}$$ and doing $z=1$ after. Now
$$E(X)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}E(X|N=n)\Pr(N=n)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}nE(Y_1)\Pr(N=n)=\lambda E(Y_1).$$

$$E(X^2)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}E(X^2|N=n)\Pr(N=n)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}(nE(Y_1^2)+n(n-1)(E(Y_1))^2)\Pr(N=n)=\lambda E(Y^2_1)+\lambda^2(E(Y_1))^2.$$
As a consequence the variance of $X^2$ is $$E(X^2)-(E(X))^2=\lambda E(Y_1)^2=\lambda\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}y^2\nu(dy)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}y^2v(dy)$$ as desired.

Comment: Nice answer. I did't think about probability generating functions and their relation with moments. Would you be able also to calculate it directly by doing the integral involving the $\text{CPoi}_v$ probability measure? I would really like this to see what I am doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Try the Laplace transform:  $L(\theta)=e^{k(\theta)}$ with $k(\theta)=-\lambda+\int_{R}e^{\theta x}v(dx)$ called the cumulant transform. It is known that $k'(0)=E(X)$ and $k''(0)=\sigma^2(X).$

Comment: I didn’t know about the cumulano transform, thanks for tip. Clearly, if you want to try solve the integral using the definition of variance, you are welcome ;-)

Comment: Well, this is standard business, by writing the Taylor formula $$1+\theta E(X)+\theta^2E(X^2)/2+O(\theta^2)=L(\theta)=e^{k(\theta)}= 1+\theta k'(0)+\theta^2(k''(0)+k'(0)^2)/2+O(\theta^2).$$

Comment: I mean $o(\theta^2)$, not $O(\theta^2).$